# JBoss: What does the warning EJBTHREE-1246 from the InterceptorRegistry mean?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, warnings, session-bean

I am currently developing an EJB 3.0 based application on the JBoss AS 5.0.0.GA and just recently the following warning showed up in the server log:

```
09:50:19,735 WARN  [InterceptorsFactory] EJBTHREE-1246: Do not use InterceptorsFactory with a ManagedObjectAdvisor, InterceptorRegistry should be used via the bean container
09:50:19,735 WARN  [InterceptorsFactory] EJBTHREE-1246: Do not use InterceptorsFactory with a ManagedObjectAdvisor, InterceptorRegistry should be used via the bean container
09:50:19,735 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for ...
...
```

The warnings are generated as soon as an EJB (a stateless session bean) is injected into a backing bean of my JSF web-application. The beans do work without problems though, but I still would like to know where that warning comes from and what I can do to avoid it.

I have already searched a bit around, but haven't found a good answer (some say, bean developers do not have to worry, but its a warning, so I'd like to have a better solution):

- http://www.jboss.com/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&t=147292
- http://www.jboss.com/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&p=4180366
- http://www.jboss.com/index.html?module=bb&op=viewtopic&p=4140136
- [JBoss JIRA Issue about the warning](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/EJBTHREE-1246) (Not that helpful in my opinion)

So has anyone an explanation what causes the warning (in terms of a bean developer, not application server developer) and what to do to avoid it?

**Update:** I've just upgraded JBoss to 5.0.1.GA ([Download](http://www.jboss.org/downloading/?projectId=jbossas&url=https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=22866&package_id=16942&release_id=663566), [Release-Notes](https://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=663566&group_id=22866)) but unfortunatly the warning still appears.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I understand all the available sources on this warning, it is nothing a user of JBoss 5 can do anything about and is essentially just a reminder for the developers of JBoss that they use their own classes wrong.

Following the advice from the developers, I am now ignoring it by changing my logging configuration in conf/jboss-log4j.xml. I've just added:

```
<category name="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors">
    <priority value="ERROR" />
</category>
```

Answer (score 7):

Even the JBoss EJB3 tutorial/documentation says you can safely ignore these warnings. Well if everyone can ignore these don't log them! It's frustrating to see this issue isn't being fixed.

Comment: Exactly! I don't know why I, as the user of their product have to know about warnings generated by internal parts which I can't control and thus can do nothing about to fix the warning.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, modify the ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml, and now works ok.

Comment: comment this lines :
<aspect name="InterceptorsFactory" factory="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorsFactory" scope="PER_INSTANCE"/>

and 
<advice name="invoke" aspect="InterceptorsFactory"/>

Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this modification in ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml

I've comment these lines :

```
<aspect name="InterceptorsFactory" factory="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorsFactory" scope="PER_INSTANCE"/>  
<advice name="invoke" aspect="InterceptorsFactory"/>
```

and it Works

Answer (score 0):

The warnings no longer appear in JBoss 5.1.0, but adding the category as Simon posted eliminates the logging of the warnings in 5.0.x

Comment: They still appear in JBoss 5.1.0 GA: 15:24:22,083 WARN  [InterceptorsFactory] EJBTHREE-1246: Do not use InterceptorsFactory with a ManagedObjectAdvisor, InterceptorRegistry should be used via the bean container

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps

1. Stop JBoss and right click on the server instance and select clean
2. right click on the project and select run -> run configurations
3. select classpath -> add jars
4. Add Jars from  JBoss ASHOME/client - `jbossall-client.jar`,JBoss ASHome/common/lib - all jars.
5. Apply and run.